# jQuery issue with toggle show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create custom toggle script to show/hide content but I am getting issue with script.

When I Click to Filter text content will display and when I click to close button again, it will close and re-open. Why this is happening I don't know please some one guide me.

My JSCode:

```
$(".rmm2-toggled").click(function () {
    $(".rmm2-toggled ul").show(1000);
});

$("#filter_close").click(function () {
    $(".rmm2-toggled ul").hide(1000);
});
```

My JSFiddle: [Sample](http://goo.gl/RppJWX)

Answer (score 4):

The click is bubbling up, so both event handlers are executed.
You need to stop the propagation

```
$(".rmm2-toggled").click(function () {
    $(".rmm2-toggled ul").show(1000);
});

$("#filter_close").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
    $(".rmm2-toggled ul").hide(1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLgVT/3/)

Answer (score 1):

hey the problem is that ur close button is inside ur toggle event

use this js code instead:

```
$(".rmm2-toggled .rmm2-toggled-title").click(function (e) {
  $(".rmm2-toggled ul").show(1000);
});

$("#filter_close").click(function (e) {
  $(".rmm2-toggled ul").hide(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to try this:

```
$(".rmm2-toggled").click(function () {
   $(".rmm2-toggled ul").show(1000, function(){
          $("#filter_close").click(function () {
            $(".rmm2-toggled ul").hide(1000);
          });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Override

```
<div class="rmm2-toggled-title" >Click to Filter</div>
```

with this

```
<div class="rmm2-toggled-title" id="open_filter">Click to Filter</div>
```

just add **ID** named "open_filter" which would be unique and close button is not inside this div.

rather adding event to parent div , add click event to its childs

updated Jquery

```
$("#open_filter").click(function () {
    $(".rmm2-toggled ul").show(1000);
});

$("#filter_close").click(function () {
    $(".rmm2-toggled ul").hide(1000);
});
```